# inventory Order management in drupal

Tags: 7, forms, ubercart

I am in search of a drupal Module for simple inventory tracker. Please see me as a novice in drupal.

My requirement is that, there are 3 levels. 
A least level employee request for a inventory item to 2nd level. 2nd level manager approves and sends it to first level, First level manager approves/denies, replies the employee with the details. These items should be tracked with an inventory management tracker thereby showing current status for each requested items.

please suggest me the drupal module for it. I think ubercart is too much for this simple application.

Will CCK along with users module enough for this application? Any suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: take a look at https://drupal.org/project/commerce_stock module

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please avoid "comparison with other CMS" questions, as it is a way to get question closed. They are off-topic here. Now, if you want to know if and how Drupal can handle your workflow, please bear in mind many of us here are not native speakers. Large blocks of text are hard to understand. Could you please format it a bit to make it more clear and easier to read?

Comment: @Mołot: Please review and let me know the clarity of my question

Comment: Good enough for me. Could use some love from users with more experience with workflows and Drupal-based commerce (I think there are other names in mainstream use for some things you described, but I can't really tell), but it is readable and on-topic now. And I admit ready-made module like that does not exist or is really hard to find. @Bala is your suggestion still valid?

Comment: @Mołot as you said, there is no ready-made module except D4, but I guess commerce stock  maybe give him an idea.

Comment: @Bala - I tried the module. Could you help me how to create user levels (roles) for it.